# Play/stop music with classes in kivy

Tags: python, oop, audio, kivy

I'm trying to execute this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader,Sound
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string('''
<MenuPage>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Button:
            text:'play'
            on_press:root.plays()
        Button:
            text:'stop'
            on_press:root.stops()
''') 


class Music(Sound):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load('/home/hosein/Music/Man.mp3')


class MenuPage(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        self.M = Music()

    def plays(self):
        self.M.play()

    def stops(self):
        self.M.stop()

music = Music()
sm = ScreenManager()
menu = MenuPage(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm




TestApp().run()
```

https://gist.github.com/daryasary/f69e1d0444ae70ff5296

There should be just two buttons to play or stop a song.

But it doesn't work.  What is the solution?

Also, is there any way to make the play and stop buttons into a single button, where the first touch plays the song and the second stops it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be something like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader,Sound
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string('''
<MenuPage>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Button:
            text:'song'
            on_press:root.plays()
''')

class MenuPage(Screen):
    M = SoundLoader.load('/home/hosein/Music/Man.mp3')

    def plays(self):
        if MenuPage.M.state == 'stop':
            MenuPage.M.play()
        else:
            MenuPage.M.stop()


sm = ScreenManager()
menu = MenuPage(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm




TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use one button, you could try using Kivy's [ToggleButton](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.togglebutton.html) and play music when the toggle button's state is 'down' and not play music when the state is 'normal'.

```
<MenuPage>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        ToggleButton:
            id: music_button
            text:'play'
            on_press:root.play_or_stop()
''')

class MenuPage(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        self.M = Music()

    def play_or_stop(self):
        if self.music_button.state == 'down':
            self.music_button.text = "Stop"
            self.M.play()
        else:
            self.music_button.text = "Play"
            self.M.stop()
```

Or, you could use a regular button that sets a variable to either True or False each time it's pressed. You can then have this value determine whether the music plays or stops.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `Sound` wrong. You should not be subclassing `Sound` or trying to create a new instance directly.

`SoundLoader.load` returns a `Sound` instance created using one of the available audio providers - this should be used instead. Try something like this:

```
class MenuPage(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        self.M = SoundLoader.load('/home/hosein/Music/Man.mp3')

    def plays(self):
        self.M.play()

    def stops(self):
        self.M.stop()

    def toggle(self):
        self.M.state = 'play' if self.M.state == 'stop' else 'play'
        return self.M.state
```

Comment: thanks! your right, but the problem is still alive. in the __main__ of program i can't use >>>menu = MenuPage(name='menu') !!!

Comment: That sounds like a different problem, and you should ask a separate question for it.